# How do I set a session attribute that includes an EL expression in Gatling?

Tags: java, gatling

I have a POST request which might have some different properties depending on my scenario. I'm trying to `exec(session -> session.set("payload", ...))` to store the appropriate template for the request before the actual call to `post().body(StringBody("#{payload}"))` but then any EL tags in the template aren't being replaced.

I'm guessing `StringBody()` doesn't process EL tags inside the value recovered by an EL tag.

How could I have a variable body for my post and still have the EL tags in it processed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ElFileBody` instead `StringBody`

https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/http/request/#elfilebody